# SQLSERVER Tabla con doble key

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando tablas en SQlserver en base a una estructura que yo no diseñé, es la siguiente
:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las tablas que tengo señaladas comparten foreign key pero además están marcadas como doble clave primaria. No sé si un foreign key se puede usar como clave primaria y si una tabla puede tener dos primary keys.

Comment: primero que todo, es MySQL o SQL Server?. En segundo lugar, hay un problema de comprensión de lo que significa una clave primaria "doble" (que dos columnas conforman la clave primaria de una tabla), con tener 2 claves primarias en la misma tabla (algo que no se puede). No entiendo la duda si una "foreign key" puede usarse como clave primaria?, son 2 cosas completamente diferentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienen doble llave primaria, es una llave primaria compuesta. Esto quiere decir que en la tabla `Tienda_Empleado` la combinación entre `Cod_Tienda` y `Documento` tiene que ser única, aunque haya valores repetidos en ambas columnas. Lo mismo pasa con la tabla `Pedido`, en la cual es la combinación de 3 columnas las que debe de ser única.

El script podría ser algo así

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tienda_Empleado(
    cod_tienda char(10) NOT NULL,
    documento int NOT NULL,
    Funcion varchar(100) NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Table_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (cod_tienda, documento);
```

El diseño en general se ve con algunas fallas, pero esa no es una de ellas.